# Do you really get double penalized for rolling HSA excess contributions to the next year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa

I'm filing my taxes with HR Block and I'm concerned that what I'm being told about my excess HSA contribution may not be accurate. I'm told that if I roll the excess into the next year then:

1. I pay income tax on the excess
2. I also pay a 6% excise tax
3. I have to contribute less the amount of the excess this year.

If it was 2) and either 1) or 3) then that would make some sense. But 1) *and* 3) doesn't sound right to me. Being in the 22% tax bracket, and the excess being $2,650, that would mean I'm really being penalized to the tune of $742 between 2) and 3).

Is that right? I understand there may be another option for me to just withdraw the excess before filing and I may pursue that option, but I also have questions about that so I will make a separate post about it. And even if that is a better option, if it turns out that using this option wasn't explained to me properly and I would really only be penalized the 6% excise tax then I may go ahead with this option just for the convenience so I definitely do want to get clarification here even if I have a better option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I pay income tax on the excess

Yes. You deduct it in the year when it's no longer excess.

> I also pay a 6% excise tax

Yes. You pay it for *every* year you're in excess.

> I have to contribute less the amount of the excess this year.

Yes. That's how you reduce your excess.

> I understand there may be another option for me to just withdraw the excess before filing

That's correct. Including earnings.

See the [IRS Publication 969](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p969#en_US_2022_publink1000204078).

Comment: Ah, the part I was missing was that I *can* deduct it in the following year. So in my case, I could contribute $5100 for 2023 but would still reduce my income for the year by $7750 after adding in the $2650 that was rolled over. That makes a lot more sense. Thank you!

Comment: That's right, although one has to wonder if it's worth the 6% penalty.

Comment: Not really, but I just want to get my taxes done and move on and if the amount were more money than I had in my account and I had to wait until I contributed enough to withdraw then I might have just rolled it over to be done with it. But, thankfully, I did end up having enough left in my account to withdraw so I was able to do that.